# Laravel 5.4 Getting MethodNotAllowedHttpException when doing POST request

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I'm working on a project that gets user from the db table. I'm trying to create an update method - ***SaveUpdatedItems()*** and I'm incorporating form validation upon submit. But I'm getting *MethodNotAllowedHttpExException* whenever I submit with incomplete fields. I've also create a method - ***SaveItems()*** for saving new record and incorporated the form validation but I'm not getting an error there. I'm fairly new to Laravel. Any ideas why I'm getting the error? Snippet of code below.

```
public function ValidateFormInput($request){
        return $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required',
            'role' => 'required',
        ]);
    }

public function SaveUpdatedItems(Request $request){
   $this->ValidateFormInput($request);
}

public function SaveItems(Request $request){

        $this->ValidateFormInput($request);
}
```

Routes:

```
Route::post('/manage/user/save', 'UserController@SaveItems');
Route::post('/manage/user/saveupdated','UserController@SaveUpdatedItems');
```

update-user.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                     <div class="navbar-container">
                        {!! Menu::get('MyNavBar')->asUl(
                            ['class' => 'nav navbar-nav nav-pills'],
                            ['class'=>'dropdown-menu']
                        ) !!}
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="panel-body">
                    <h2>Update User</h2>

                     @if ($errors->any())
                        <div class="alert alert-danger">
                            <ul>
                                @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                                    <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                                @endforeach
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    @endif

                    {{Form::open(array('action' => 'UserController@SaveUpdatedItems', 'method' => 'post','files' => true))}}
                    {{ Form::hidden('_token', csrf_token() ) }}
                    @foreach($items as $item)
                     {{ Form::hidden('id[]', $item->id) }}
                     <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-sm">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Name:</td>
                                <td>{{ Form::text('name', $item->name ,array('class' => 'form-control')) }}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Email:</td>
                                <td>{{ Form::text('email', $item->email, array('class' => 'form-control')) }}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Password:</td>
                                <td>{{ Form::password('password', array('class' => 'form-control')) }}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Role:</td>
                                <td>{{Form::select('role', $roles , null ,['class' => 'form-control'])}}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Active (?):</td>
                                <td>{{Form::select('is_active' , array('' => '-----', 1 => 'Yes', 0 => 'No'),  $item->is_active,['class' => 'form-control'])}}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Aprroved (?):</td>
                                <td>{{Form::select('is_approved', array('' => '-----', 1 => 'Yes', 0 => 'No'), $item->is_approved, ['class' => 'form-control'])}}</td>
                            </tr>


                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    @endforeach
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                    {!! Form::close() !!}
                    <br>
                    <a href="/manage/user"> <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">View Users</button></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@endsection

@section('scripts')
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){

        });
</script>
@endsection
```

Comment: post your routes and the form itself.

Comment: Maybe you route is being oveeride by another route

Comment: just checked, there is only 1 - Route::post('/manage/user/saveupdated','UserController@SaveUpdatedItems');

Comment: What is the route and controller action that shows the `update-user.blade.php` view?

Answer (score 1):

When your validation fails, Laravel will redirect you back to the page that submitted the invalid data. This redirect will be a GET request.

So, if you happen to be on a page that is only accessible via POST, and then you submit a form that has validation errors, you will get redirected back to that page with a GET request, causing a `MethodNotAllowedHttpExException` error.

Comment: Aha. Makes sense :-) So how do you suggest I make a work around for this?

Comment: @wendecat Well, the best option would be to restructure everything so that you conform to normal resource routing. [This talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MF0jFKvS4SI) by Adam Wathan gives you the idea. But, that can take a bit of time and effort. If you just want a quick workaround to get around this, just allow your route to handle GET requests, too.

Comment: thanks for info. Just changed that route to get. Everything's much simpler that way. It was just a dumb mistake. Thanks.